# Is java.awt.Frame supporting inner frame?

Tags: java, swing, awt, frame

I want to create multiple inner frames through `java.awt.Frame`? I know it is possible through `JInternalFrame`.

Comment: Why would you want to use AWT which is a dead technology no longer being supported by Oracle? This means it has several bugs in it and you should be using Swing or JavaFx to do this anyway?

Comment: @Frakcool I have an application with 1000+ Java files which implement with awt package. On that application, I need to implement inner-frame things. https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/source/index.html

Comment: A Frame is a top level container. You can't add a Frame to a Frame. You can add one or more child components, such as a Panel, to a Frame. The Panel can be decorated to "look like a frame". This is how the JInternalFrame works in Swing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is No.

An AWT Frame is a container and not a component.  That means you can't put a frame into anything else.

The modelling of Swing is different.  There `JInternalFrame` class is a Swing component that behaves like a `JFrame` but can be (must be) nested within a `JFrame`.  There is no equivalent class in AWT.

For more information about components, containers, windows, and frames in AWT, read this reference:

- [Chapter 6](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-awt-reference/9781565922402/09_chapter-06.html) of Java AWT Reference by John Zukowski

---

> I have an application with 1000+ Java files which implement with AWT package. On that application, I need to implement inner-frame things.

There is no easy solution.  You would need implement your own version of internal frame in AWT.  I don't know if that is feasible, let alone a good idea.  (I didn't come across any examples when I googled it.  But maybe you could.)

It might be time to consider porting the UI implementation for your Java application to use something more modern like Swing, JavaFX or HTML 5, though that will be a lot of dev work.  Arguable, this work *should have been* done a long time ago.  Swing was first introduced in 1997, and JavaFX in 2005.  You now have roughly 20 years of accumulated UI dev work that needs to be redone ... if you want your UI design to stay "fresh".

Alternatively, you could push back on the requirement as being too difficult or *too expensive* to implement.

Alternatively, maybe it is time for a ground-up re-implementation.  (Or retiring the application.)